# Using RSA-SH1 signature for OAuth 1 with Paw

Tags: oauth, paw-app

According to Xero support I can only use an **RSA-SH1** signature to connect to their API so I am wondering if there is a configuration option or extension available for Paw to allow me to make RSA-SH1 signed OAuth 1 calls.

I am trying to use Paw for mac to test endpoints of the Xero API. I have followed Xero's instructions of setting up a private application. This gives me the right consumer key and secret for making API calls.

Next I am trying to use Paw to test these endpoints before I integrate the API into my project.

Unfortunately though my requests cannot be made. When I setup my authorization header in Paw there is no **RSA-SH1** signature method choice. See screen shot:

[image: Paw Screenshot]

Comment: There's no specific reason why we didn't add RSA-SHA1 yet, but I've added that on our task list for a next version. That makes a lot of sense. My guess is that it isn't as much used as the HMAC-SHA1, and that's probably why we haven't added this at first.

Comment: @MichaMazaheri Still doesn't work for Xero as theres no signature added, or rather its blank. Also no option to add your own cert.